# DevCpp6.3---An error occurs when opening CPP files with Chinese annotations

Tags: c++, dev-c++

[How to solve this problem? An error occurs when using DevCpp6.3 to open CPP files with Chinese annotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF6po.png)

Comment: Looks like you did the smart thing [and raised an issue with the devteam](https://github.com/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/issues/220}. They'll be able to help you a lot better than we can here, but I recommend providing more information, like a file that triggers the error and the full steps you take to cause the error. Don't worry about the information feeling stupid or obvious to you. The less ambiguity in the error report, the sooner it will be resolved or worked-around.

Comment: If you post a bug report with nothing but a picture in it , the response you'll get from the developers is similar to what you have so far gotten here: Silence. Give them everything they need to reproduce the problem, and you'll get results (although sometimes the result is, "Uhhh... Yeah. Uhm... We can't fix that."